# C program to store special characters in strings

Tags: c, string

Basically, I can't figure this out, I want my C program to store the entire plaintext of a batch program then insert in a file and then run.

I finished my program, but holding the contents is my problem. How do I insert the code in a string and make it ignore ALL special characters like %s \ etc?

Comment: Huh? Why don't you provide a simple example of what you're trying to do, along with the code you've written, and an explanation of why that code isn't meeting your needs.

Comment: Hi, could you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29658418/edit) so that it [includes the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: You'll need to double up the \ characters when declaring anything literal in a string, such as say `echo C:\\myfile.txt`, and the `%` characters too.

Comment: You can work with the string directly. Loop through each position of the character array and if you have a special character then just replace it with something else using a switch-case. You can replace it with a whitespace for example.

Comment: what about " and ' and & etc is there any documentation on how to cancel each character?

Comment: Is this previous answer any help as a reference? In the absence of any detailed requirement, it's "whistling in the wind". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316718/how-to-run-and-modify-a-cmd-script-or-file-in-c/29316880#29316880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape special characters with a \, you can escape backslash itself with another backslash (i.e. `\\`).

Comment: @MuchMemezMuchWow You don't have to do it manually - you can write another program to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian previously mentioned, you can escape characters that aren't allowed in normal C strings with `\`; for instance, newline becomes `\n`, double-quote becomes `\"`, and backslash becomes `\\`.

If you're unable or unwilling to do this for whatever reason, then you may be out of luck if you're solution must be in C.  However, if you're willing to switch to C++, then you can use [raw strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
World
)foo";
```

This is equivalent to

```
const char* s2 = "\nHello\nWorld\n";
```

A raw string must begin with `R"` followed by an arbitrary delimiter (made of any source character but parentheses, backslash and spaces; can be empty; and at most 16 characters long), then `(`, and must end with `)` followed by the delimiter and `"`.  The delimiter must be chosen such that the termination substring (`)`, delimiter, `"`) does not appear within the string.